# Codes of multimedia keys

Tags: c#

What are the codes for multimedia keys `sendkey`, keys like <kbd>stop</kbd>, <kbd>play</kbd>, <kbd>add sound</kbd>, <kbd>turn down</kbd>, <kbd>mute</kbd>?

Answer (score 8):

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys.aspx) reference.

Answer (score 0):

Look in `Keys` Enum, play is an OR like this: `Play = Exsel | OemBackslash,`

Comment: It is a good hint IMHO, that the codes are representing other keys in combination of ORs or ANDs...

Comment: Keys Enum is not a series of Flags so ORing them is meaningless.

Comment: [Actually is is:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys.aspx) _This enumeration has a FlagsAttribute attribute that allows a bitwise combination of its member values._

Answer (score 0):

I don't have such a keyboard, but i would think:

1. they differ from manufacturer to manufacturer
2. some of these keys will be received by the driver of the keyboard manufacturer and will create some kind of action directly their without propagating them to the OS as a normal key event.

To get a clue for your specific keyboard you should make a small test application containing a Form, set the `KeyPreview` to `true` and simply subscribe to the `KeyDown` event of it. Their you'll put maybe some code like this:

```
private void FormMain_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(e.KeyData.ToString());
}
```

So you get in the Output Window of Visual Studio visualized the pressed key.