# Global media control in c#

Tags: c#, windows, media-player, sendkeys

I want to control Windows media globally. All I need are the basics. Pause/Play, next, previous, Volume up and down. Similar to what the media keys (VK_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE, etc.) do. Simulating the keys with `SendKeys.Send` or `SendKeys.SendWait()` does not work, since these functions only take strings and the media keys are not recognized.

Existing classes for windows media like the MediaPlayer class (https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.media.mediaplayer(v=vs.110).aspx) seem to be designed for building new media players, rather than controlling existing ones.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send multimedia commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15013582/send-multimedia-commands)