# Is there any way to Invoke the universal Play/Pause controls on Windows using C#?

Tags: c#

I'm making an app that will pause/play music on an event. I am not making my own music player, rather I'd like to use the universal pause/play that windows has System wide. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: The Multimdia Keys are part of the [Key enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys.aspx).

Comment: See if any of these post help you: [Send key “MediaPlayPause”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199203/send-key-mediaplaypause-to-an-application-without-setting-focus-to-it),  [Send keys through SendInput](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761169/send-keys-through-sendinput-in-user32-dll),  [Send multimedia commands](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15013582/send-multimedia-commands),  [Codes of multimedia keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986417/codes-of-multimedia-keys) - Please report if anyone does help and maybe post the solution and an answer!

Comment: Reading through all this, it seems making your own player is simpler after all..

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use the [`keybd_event`](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.keybd_event) windows API to do this.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
...
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags,
    UIntPtr dwExtraInfo);
public const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x0002;
public const byte VK_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE = 0xB3;

private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // No flags indicate key down
    keybd_event(VK_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE, 0, 0, UIntPtr.Zero);
    keybd_event(VK_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, UIntPtr.Zero);
}
```

For a full list of key codes, you can use this class:

https://github.com/johnkoerner/KeyboardListener/blob/master/KeyboardListener/Keycodes.cs

Comment: Can you comment a little on this? Will it work with any application playing the e.g. music? Will it work without a MMKeyboard ? I tried and it seems to do nothing..

Comment: Oh well, checking out Hans' post it seems this is not that easy..